# postfix transport to smtp or lmtp depending on LDAP attribute

Tags: postfix, routing, ldap, attributes

In postfix, I usually route mails depending on "mailhost" attribute as follows:

```
query_filter = (|(&(mail=%U@%d)(accountstatus=active))(&(mailalternateaddress=%U@%d)(accountstatus=active)))
result_attribute = mailhost
result_format = smtp:[%s]
```

But due to a flow change, I need to send some mails over smtp and others over lmtp depending on the same attribute. ¿How can I perform that?

Thanks in advance for your help